# Is type declaration a big part of the positives of static typed languages?

Tags: static-typing

Statically typed programming languages do type checking at compiling. Is type declaration an important reason that is making them significantly faster?

Comment: You can write very complex (say) Haskell programs without ever adding a type declaration/signature, the compiler will **infer** the types and produce efficient code. So: are type declarations necessary to have efficient code? No. Apart from that there is a huge field about compiling/tpye inference etc. Your question is way too broad and open ended.

Comment: static type checking reduces the amount of time spent compiling the code as it doesn't need to use as much type interference. If the amount of time and resources spent compiling is limited, the compiler can spend more time on optimising other aspects of the application. This makes it more practical to compile the code more efficiently to native code.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta haskell has other restrictions on things like side effects to improve efficiency ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey You understood the question and answered what's needed. The question was talking about static typed languages not that declarations are important for all kinds of languages, thanks.The guy above you not so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A statically typed language is one in which the type of every variable is known at compile-time. In some languages like C, C++, Java the programmer must manually specify the type and in other languages like Haskell and Scala has some form of `type inference`, the capability of the type system to deduce the type of a variable.

**Does it make them faster?**
1. Figuring out the type at compile-time does reduce a lot of overhead for the run-time.
 
2. Because the types are figured out earlier on, even functions/ methods in the language are well defined into static addresses. Where as in a dynamically typed language names are based on strings. And for each method access, lookups have to be done. Which are many, causing the language to be slower.

Answer (score -1):

yes static declarations of variables improves execution speed